# How to get result from stored procedure, the procedure runs fine but php returns null

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have an stored procedure running on my mysql server with this code:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`present`@`%` PROCEDURE `InsertNewEventOrderItems`(IN `UserIDParam` INT, IN `Time` VARCHAR(255), IN `EventIDParam` INT, OUT `Result` VARCHAR(255))
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

    DECLARE OrderIDVar INT DEFAULT 0;

    IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM _newapp_shop_orders where UserID=UserIDParam AND Status='Open')) THEN

        SELECT OrderID INTO OrderIDVar FROM _newapp_shop_orders WHERE UserID=UserIDParam AND Status='Open';

        IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM _newapp_shop_order_items WHERE OrderID=OrderIDVar AND EventID=EventIDParam)) THEN  

            -- User has open order so create a new order item!

            SELECT OrderID INTO OrderIDVar FROM _newapp_shop_orders WHERE UserID=UserIDParam AND Status='Open';

            INSERT INTO _newapp_shop_order_items (OrderID, EventID, ActivityID, Price, Amount) VALUES (OrderIDVar, EventIDParam, NULL, (SELECT Price FROM _newapp_shop_products_events WHERE EventID=EventIDParam), 1);

            -- SELECT 'InsertOrderItem' INTO Result;  

            SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO Result;

        ELSE 

            UPDATE _newapp_shop_order_items SET Amount=Amount + 1 WHERE OrderID=OrderIDVar AND EventID=EventIDParam;

            -- SELECT 'UpdateOrderItem' INTO Result;

            SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO Result;

        END IF;


    ELSE 

        -- User has no open order so create a new order!

        INSERT INTO _newapp_shop_orders (UserID, Created, Modified) VALUES (UserIDParam, Time, Time);

        SELECT OrderID INTO OrderIDVar from _newapp_shop_orders where UserID=UserIDParam AND Status='Open';

        IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM _newapp_shop_order_items WHERE OrderID=OrderIDVar AND EventID=EventIDParam)) THEN  

            -- User has made a new order item so create a new order item!

            INSERT INTO _newapp_shop_order_items (OrderID, EventID, ActivityID, Price, Amount) VALUES (OrderIDVar, EventIDParam, NULL, (SELECT Price FROM _newapp_shop_products_events WHERE EventID=EventIDParam), 1);

            -- SELECT 'InsertOrderItem' INTO Result;  

            SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO Result;  

        ELSE 
            -- User has made an existing order item so update the order item!

            UPDATE _newapp_shop_order_items SET Amount=Amount + 1 WHERE OrderID=OrderIDVar AND EventID = EventIDParam;

            -- SELECT 'UpdateOrderItem' INTO Result;

            SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO Result;

        END IF;

    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It inserts a new order, order item or updates an existing item, it returns the modified rows to check if the insert was succesfull. When i execute the procedure in phpmyadmin it result the inserted rows fine and it inserts the proper rows in the belonging tables. But when i run this procedure from php, it returns just NULL, this is my php code:

```php
public function pushItemToCart($userID, $item)
    {
        $itemList = json_decode($item);
        if ($itemList->Type == 'events') {
            $sql = 'CALL `InsertNewEventOrderItems`(?, ?, ?, @Result)';
        } elseif ($itemList->Type == 'activities') {
            $sql = 'CALL `InsertNewActivityOrderItems`(?, ?, ?, @Result)';
        }

        if ($query = $this->DB->prepare($sql)) {
            $nowFormat = mktime(
                date('H'),
                date('i'),
                date('s'),
                date('m'),
                date('d'),
                date('Y')
            );

            $query->bind_param('isi', $userID, $nowFormat, $itemList->Id);

            $query->execute();

            $query->next_result();

            $select = $this->DB->query('SELECT @Result;');

            //$query->execute();

            $result = $select->fetch_assoc();

            $query->close();

            echo json_encode($result['@Result']);

            exit();
        } else {
            $error = $this->DB->errno . ' ' . $this->DB->error;

            echo json_encode('405'); // 1054 Unknown column 'foo' in 'field list'

            exit();
        }
    }
```

So i expect the result to be 1 or 2 or 0

Comment: you need more >next_result(); calls

Comment: You probably should include the actual CREATE PROCEDURE portion of that sql.

Comment: @Uueerdo Updated my question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense At what position in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by removing the second execute and fully checking the procedure on errors. Correct code in the main post.